# TeXstudio not recognizing standard commands imported via custom package

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting

I organize my long LaTeX documents (in the document class `book`) by splitting them into various files in a common folder:

1. A `.sty` file that contains all the `RequirePackage` and custom commands.
2. `chapter.tex` files.
3. `master.tex` file that weaves everything together.

Everything was going nice and smooth until recently when TeXstudio, in one of my "books", refused to recognize the standard commands (like `\mathbb`) that I import via the `.sty` file. (The output is however okay.) It's never done like so before.

Here's an MWE (`master.tex` is redundant for this, hence omitting):

```
%----------------
%   problem.sty
%----------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{problem}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
```

```
%----------------
%   problem.tex
%----------------
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{[PACKAGE]}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbb C$
\end{document}
```

How it looks in the editor:

1. When I run the `.tex` file with `[PACKAGE]` being `amssymb`, everything is good:[image]
2. But with `[PACKAGE]` being my `problem.sty`, TeXstudio no longer recognizes `\mathbb`:[image]

Comment: You need to create your own completion file `problem.cwl`. Instructions [here](https://texstudio-org.github.io/background.html#description-of-the-cwl-format)